# How center #+BEGIN_EXAMPLE on org-mode LaTeX export?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I have a verbatim/monospaced block that way:

```
#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
                                   _
                                /     \
                               T       H
                             /   \   /   \
                            T     H T     H
#+END_EXAMPLE
```

On the LaTeX->PDF export I get:

[image]

I know that the spaces doesn't matter, but how center it on export? I tried wrap the content with `#+BEGIN_CENTER` but doesn't works. I tried set `\centering` before and doesn't works too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use raw latex commands in an org-mode document, which we can use to get around not being able to nest BEGIN_CENTER and BEGIN_EXAMPLE:

```
#+BEGIN_CENTER
\begin{verbatim}
                                   _
                                /     \
                               T       H
                             /   \   /   \
                            T     H T     H
\end{verbatim}

blah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blah
#+END_CENTER
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you still need this? Have your tried wrapping your diagram with `@@latex:...@@`. I propose:

```
@@latex:\begin{center}@@
                                   _
                                /     \
                               T       H
                             /   \   /   \
                            T     H T     H
@@latex:\end{center}@@
```

Comment: Or, alternatiuvely, `#+LATEX: \begin{center}` alone on a line instead of the in-line version`@@latex: \begin{center}@@`.

See the [documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Quoting-LaTeX-code.html)..